# How can I use a formula to match multiple criteria from a different table in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fill in several columns in a table based on data from another table. If an email exists in the original table, and its row also has a value that matches the `Source` column, return `true`.

This is what my original source table looks like.

```
Email            | Source
---------------------------
james@help.com   | A
james@help.com   | B
mike@me.com      | A
greg@please.com  | C
mike@me.com      | A
```

And this is what my results table looks like.

```
Email            | A   | B   | C
-----------------------------------
james@help.com   | Yes | Yes |
mike@me.com      | Yes |     |
greg@please.com  |     |     | Yes
mike@me.com      | Yes |     |
```

Columns with the headings `A`, `B`, and `C` would be the formulas checking for a `true` or `false` value based on the above table. The formula would then enter "Yes" for `true` or leave the cell blank for `false`.

Here is an example of what the formula would look like in Column A. I attempt to match `Email` to `Email`, and then the string "A" to the `Source` column. Unfortunately this returns true for all rows.

`=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH([Email],source[Email],0),MATCH("A",source[Source],0)),"Yes",""),"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe can be achieved with a CountIFs function. Type the email addresses and the source types into the row and column headers of your result table, then use the formula

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E2,$B:$B,F$1),"Yes","")
```

Adjust the ranges to suit your environment but take care with the relative and absolute references to ensure the formula looks at the correct ranges when copied to the right.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would use a VLOOKUP.  Not sure exactly how you need it look but it should be something like this.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

```
=VLOOKUP([Email], source[Email], 2)
=VLOOKUP($A1, source[A:B], 2)
```

This will give you the value.

Now just compare that to the value at the top of the column.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

```
=IF(VLOOKUP([Email], source[Email], 2)=B$1, "Yes", "")
=IF(VLOOKUP($A1, source[A:B], 2)=B$1, "Yes", "")
```

Comment: Downvoted because you are using VLookup without the fourth parameter, hence defaulting that to TRUE, which expects the data table to be sorted ascending by the first column, which it clearly isn't. This will lead to wrong results.

Comment: Also, VLookup on the email address will only find the first occurrence of the email address, so `james.help.com` will never be found for source `B`. You clearly did not test your suggestion.

Comment: @teylyn: Your right, I threw up my answer in a few minutes trying to be helpful.  I don't even own excel.  I bow down to your amazing MS Office skills.  Congrats on the checkmark.